# Solving the Malthusian Growth ODE (without separation of variables)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

I remember that I have seen somewhere that the simplest mathematical model of population growth
$$
\frac{{\rm d}P}{{\rm d}t}=kP
$$
[where $P$ is the population at time $t$, ${\rm d}P/{\rm d}t$ is the rate of population and $k$ is a positive constant],
can be solved without separating the variables in the differential equation. Unfortunately, I can recall neither the solution, nor the source.

For instance, say,  we are given that the population has doubled in 6 years. How long it will take to triple? [Solving the problem with separation of variables, integration and using the condition gives $t=6\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}\approx 9.5$ years.]

Comment: Intergrating factors can be used: write $P' - kP = 0.$

Comment: For not separating the variable, multiply by $e^{kt}$ each size and recognize the derivative of product then integrate.

Comment: @EDX Great! There is a misprint I think. Multiply by $e^{-kt}$ seems to work for me.